# Counting regex matches in Scala?

Tags: regex, scala

In Scala I am trying to detemine the number of types a particular match is found (and it can occur several times in the same string). Namely, something that is of form "##/nnn-#" where # is a number `0-9` and n is a letter `A-Za-z` and - is a hiphen and / is a forward slash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
scala> val reg = "[0-9]{2}/[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]".r
scala> val str = "12/abc-2 abcd 55/bar-2 foo bar"
scala> reg.findAllIn(str).length
```